# генерация нагрузки танком в оптический порт

Tags: яндекс-танк

Провожу нагрузочное тестирование вэб-сервера по оптическому каналу.

Есть ли в конфигурации танка настройка сетевых интерфейсов, куда будут выдаваться генерируемые запросы? Иными словами - можно танку напрямую указать сетевой интерфейс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о генераторе нагрузки phantom, то с помощью опции gatling_ip можно указать source ip адрес поднятый на интересующем интерфейсе. Адресов может быть несколько, разделитель списка - пробел.

```
[phantom] 
gatling_ip = 192.168.1.13 192.168.1.12
```

Comment: Если я все правильно понимаю, то с помощью данной опции можно задавать сразу несколько интерфейсов, куда будет выдаваться генерируемая нагрузка? Если так, тогда еще один небольшой подвопрос - нагрузка будет делиться по интерфейсам или исходящий трафик будет клонироваться между интерфейсами?

Comment: Да, можно указать адреса с разных , либо указать несколько ip адресов поднятых на одном интерфейсе, что бывает полезным, когда начинается нехватка портов на одном адресе. Нагрузка будет делиться по интерфейсам.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А порты можно указывать?

Comment: Судя по https://github.com/yandex-load/phantom/blob/master/phantom/io_benchmark/method_stream/ipv6/method_stream_ipv6.C#L37 и https://github.com/yandex-load/phantom/blob/master/pd/base/netaddr_ipv6.H#L28 нет, исходящему порту приписывается нулевое значение, что означает "возьми любой доступный". Для ipv4 сделано аналогично.